# Report Folders visible to Profiles without "View Reports in Public Folders"

Tags: reports-folder

I have read numerous articles & questions about Report & Dashboard Folder Sharing, but I still can't figure out what's going on.

I have c.20 Report Folders and a few Dashboard Folders.

These Folders, and the Reports within them, are visible to all Profiles, including those with *View Reports in Public Folders* set to false (unchecked), and regardless of whether they have been Shared with the User / Group.

[image]

Are these "Public Folders"? If so, why isn't the *View Reports in Public Folders* permission not having an effect? If not, how do I restrict visibility of them?

Comment: Does the `Who Can Access` information when you click `Share Folder` mention these users or a role (with hierarchy) or group they may be a part of?

Comment: Thanks @KrisGoncalves - The folders are a mixed bag, but most haven't been shared with anyone, so I would expect them to be visible to those with the *View Reports in Public Folders* permission and invisible to those without. 
For those folders that have been Shared with users / groups, my users can still see them!

Comment: does the user have a permission set that gives them that permission? It could potentially be ticked off unexpectedly in any permission set. Turning off `View Reports in Public Folders` works as expected on my end

Comment: YES! Thank you @KrisGoncalves that was it. A Permission Set had granted View Reports in Public Folders under System Permissions.